# Implicit Functions with Symbol argument in Scala

Tags: scala, symbols, implicit

Why does the following code print:

```
class TestClass{
  case class printClass(s: Symbol) {
    def pr() = println(s);
  }
  implicit def implPrint(i: Symbol) = printClass(i)
}

object TestObject extends TestClass{
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    'x pr
  }
}
```

while the following code doesn't:

```
class TestClass{
  implicit def implPrint(i: Symbol) = println(i)
}

object TestObject extends TestClass{
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    'x

    ()
  }
}
```

To my knowledge implicit functions are called automatically by the compiler if it thinks it is a good idea to. Why isn't the compiler calling `implPrint()` in both cases? What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 2):

Implicit methods are only invoked when they are needed, or there will be many unexpected behaviors. And here, you do not call the method that it does not contain on it, or if it is passed to a method that requires other types of variables, 'implPrint' will not be called.

Answer (score 2):

Implicits are considered by the compiler when it cannot understand the syntax of the code at hand. In your first example you are attempting to invoke `pr()` on a Symbol object, syntax which is not understood by the compiler, so it turns to implicits. In your second example you are declaring a Symbol and doing nothing with it, syntax which agrees with the compiler's parsing, so it does not look at implicits.